# Connect two Ubuntu Computers via ssh (internet)

Tags: networking, server, ssh, remote-access

Every tutorial I watched displayed how to connect two machines via ssh locally. But what if I want remote control via internet?

I know that IP addresses which start with 192.168 are local and invisible to internet users(of corse, 255*255 = about 65k ip adresses wouldn't be enough for millions internet devices on such big network), so I needed to know my public IP and I found it out by typing

curl icanhazip.com

in terminal.
Also, I know that port 22 is default for ssh protocol and my firewall, exactly both firewalls on machines are disabled.
Both machines use Ubuntu 16.04.
On one, which i chosen to be the server, I created .ssh directory in home folder (with permission 700) and file "authorized_users"(with permission 600) inside it. I checked

service sshd status

and restarted it, so it was being active. I (exactly my bro, which is intended to be remote user of my comp i.e. server) generated public and private key by:

ssh-keygen -t dsa

and created id_dsa and id_dsa.pub files on remote machine(not on server).
After that, I sent him my public IP(because we want ssh communication via internet, I can't see another network) and he typed:

ssh-copy-id servername@serverPublicIP

But, it did not create anything in my /home/pc/.ssh/authorized_users, and of corse after trying to connect by

ssh servername@serverPublicIP

it didn't succeed.

Comment: The reason those tutorials are about local connections is because that's how most folks learn. The first time you will make a lot of mistakes, so make those mistakes in the shallow end of the pool.  Once you know how to successfully connect two local machines, then add in keys and firewalls, then add in router port forwarding and public IPs, and finally you are ready for real remote login.

Comment: Get it working first via local IP from on the network. After that you can work to connect, I suspect it is an issue on the server as well as configuring your router. MAKE SURE YOU HARDEN YOUR SERVER I cannot say this enough. Make sure you set things up as securely as you can.

Comment: You will usually have to modify settings in your router to allow incoming connections from the internet and send them to the correct computer on your LAN.  As others have said, bots routinely scan SSH ports hundreds or thousands of times a day, so be sure you have things secure.